# Multiple index search in redis

Tags: mongodb, indexing, redis, tweets

I have a series of text data (tweets) which need to be indexed on 3 attributes. I wanted to use redis for the same as the response time has to be fast. Can anyone suggest how to go about this. Or should I go with MongoDB.

Comment: What are the attributes you want to index?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little bit confused about the term "index"... If you want to search in (JSON) data, I think ElasticSearch (http://www.elasticsearch.org/) would be the much better choice.

It you use case is mostly about geo information, have a look at

- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-geo-point-type.html
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html
- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-geohashgrid-aggregation.html

I think building this in Redis would give you a hard time. Don't get me wrong, I love Redis and I'm a huge advocate, but I think it's the wrong tool for what you want to build apparantly.

There's even a plugin for ElasticSearch which gathers the tweets for you:

https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-twitter

Comment: One of the attributes will be location of the tweet. More attributes will be added on an incremental basis. ElasticSearch looks interesting. Taking a look at it too

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, with Redis you'll need to maintain an index for each attribute you want to search on. Here's a simple example - let's say that you store your tweets like in hashes, e.g.:

```
HMSET tweet:<id> text <tweet text> time <timestamp> ...
```

To create an index on your tweets' timestamps, you'll need to maintain a sorted set with the timestamp as score and the tweet's id as the value:

```
ZADD _tweet:time <timestamp> <id>
```

This will allow you to search for certain tweets in a given time period with [ZRANGEBYSCORE](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore).

Note that you'll also have to take care of maintaining the index (modify, del). You'd also need to repeat this approach for any additional indices. If you're looking for more material, here are some slides on the subject: http://www.slideshare.net/itamarhaber/20140922-redis-tlv-redis-indices